# What are these types of soldiers called?

Tags: vocabulary

During the military service in Iran, some soldiers are responsible for traffic control (entrance and exit of people in a garrison or headquarters after writing down their names and searching them), appearance and discipline of other soldiers, opening and closing gates for vehicles, and things like that (you could say they are in charge of the building although having low ranks). What do we call them in English?

P.S. I believe the words "doorman" or "guard" wouldn't be appropriate since they do not encapsulate all of their duties.

Comment: In the US some of these duties would be the responsibility of MPs -- Military Police.

Comment: And in the UK too. [Military Police](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_police#:~:text=Military%20police%20(MP)%20are%20law,the%20military%20of%20a%20state.&text=A%20section%20of%20the%20military,by%20military%20or%20civilian%20personnel)

Comment: Different organizations use different terms. The USAF has [Security Forces](https://www.airforce.com/careers/indemand-careers/security-forces). It's both a formal designation and a bit more encompassing that MP.

Comment: Often there aren't exact correspondences between regular duties for a fixed set of troops say in country A and in country B. A private may be detailed to do 'gate sentry duty' one day and 'headquarters security duty' the next.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. So we can say "I was a sentry in my military service." Right?

Comment: It's unlikely that that would be used a 'job description' in today's armies. 'I often did sentry duty at Cliffden Barracks', say.

Comment: In my experience, everyone of a lower rank had to do "watch", or "sentry" duty at least a few  times during their early careers.    I once found myself guarding the barracks dumpster for a few nights. Didn't make me an MP, although later it included carrying a sidearm, not just a toy M1. Usually we referred to "base security", which were normally USMC. Navy MPs were called "chasers".

Comment: My understanding is that a guard or sentry can be keeping watch on anything, not just a gate (like @Cascabel and his dumpsters). Also MPs do a lot more than man gates. I would say that anyone assigned to the gate was acting as a [gatekeeper](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatekeeper). The term is often used metaphorically now but its original meaning was exactly that, controlling traffic through a gate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP is asking for an Anglicized version of a Persian rank for which there is probably no single equivalent.

Comment: Are they members of the Revolutionary Guard?

Answer (score 1):

The US military often refers to the people performing these functions as “specialists” of some kind.

For example, a search for the term “logistics specialist” led to this: https://www.navsup.navy.mil/public/navsup/home/

A search for “security specialist army” led to a number of thiings, including this description of an officer-level position that provides the names of the positions that such a person would supervise: https://www.navsup.navy.mil/public/navsup/home/

These include **Security Guards**, who are different from Military Police, in the same way that a night watchman is different from a detective.